Incomplete CSV table data import in MySQL Workbench
I have been trying to import a CSV file for SQL Practice into my MySQL Workbench database.
This particular file in question has 3,504 rows (including header) but when I import it into my database using the Table Data Import Wizard (UI method, not syntax/code), Workbench only imports the first 362 records.


So far, I've tried converting the CSV to JSON using online tools. This produced even worse results because Workbench now won't import a single record from the JSON file. Have a look


I should mention that within this database/schema there are several other tables one of which has 8,715 rows and this being a 'Music Store Data Analysis' Dataset, some of these tables have tons of text based data.
I'm not sure if there is an error in the data that would end the import operation at 362nd record...

I would share the CSV and JSON files but I don't see an option to attach either of those file types...
Update: I found a way to solve this!
I used an online tool to convert the CSV file to a SQL script (didn't know this was also an option earlier)
Link to the tool - https://www.convertcsv.com/
Not sure how reliable this site is safety wise but so far MS Defender hasn't reported anything wrong with the script I downloaded... One can also just copy the entire Insert script and run it from the query editor.
I downloaded the script and imported the data from it and got all the 3,204 records.

No issues at all, the data types for all columns seem to be appropriate and the data got imported faster this way.

On this kind of problem, I like to load the .csv file into LibreOffice Calc or Excel and look at the last row successfully imported and the first failed row. Often eyeballing the data in that part of your .csv file will show something obvious: letters where a number should be, too many letters for a varchar, that kind of thing.

LibreOffice Calc works better than Excel for this b/c Excel reformats numbers and Calc leaves them alone.

@O.Jones I've never used LibreOffice but will surely try. Thanks for the suggestion, I was looking for a way to solve this without going online.
